# How do I fill input of a read command in Linux before it runs?

Tags: bash, input

There's a script I'm running that installs a service. It has a couple of `read` commands.

I'd like to run it as a part of a bigger installation script (actually capistrano but it doesn't matter), and prefill the "read" parts with values, instead of blocking the entire process.

The script runs with a single command, let's say `blah/bin/blah install`, I'd like to supply input on the command, like `input first_input, second_input | blah/bin/blah install`

Relevant parts of the script:

```
      if [[ $NEO4J_USER == $wrapper_user ]]; then
        default_user=$wrapper_user
      else
        default_user="neo4j"
      fi

      ######### read:
      read -p "Graph-like power should be handled carefully. What user should run Neo4j? [$default_user] " proposed_user
      proposed_user=${proposed_user:-$default_user}
      if ! `id $proposed_user &> /dev/null` ; then

      ######### read:
        read -p "User \"$proposed_user\" does not yet exist. Shall I create the account for you? [Yn]" yn
        case $yn in
          [Nn]* ) echo "WARNING: Alright, but Neo4j will fail to launch until that user has been created."
          set_user $proposed_user
          ;;
        * ) create_user $proposed_user
          ;;
```

The entire script is at http://pastebin.com/RpJZciXq

I know I can change the script but I just want to prefill the values. Is it possible?

Well, in fact, it did matter I use capistrano because it has the ability to [send input](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invocation-Run) (see `&block` section).

But it's interesting to know if the functionality I mentioned exists in bash as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` reads from stdin by default. Simply feed something there.

```
echo -e '\n\n' | blah/blah/blah install

blah/blah/blah install <<< $'\n\n'
```